# serialized object from php to android view

Tags: java, serialization

well... i have a problem when i receive the string serialized , is  something like

> a:1:{i:0;a:13:{s:2:"id";s:7:"1301087";s:6:"NOMBRE";s:12:"XxXxXx XXXXX";s:8:"XXXXXXXX";s:16:"XXXXXXX XXLLXXXX";s:4:"SEXO";s:1:"M";s:8:"XXXXXXXX";s:1:"P";s:7:"XXX_NAC";s:10:"1993-29-13";s:6:"DEPART";s:6:"XXXXXX";s:8:"DISTRITO";s:1:"0";s:4:"ZONA";s:4:"ENCA";s:5:"LOCAL";s:1:"8";s:4:"MESA";s:2:"20";s:5:"ORDEN";s:2:"42";s:6:"CEDULA";s:7:"2692282";}}

in php before i serialize the object i have this

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 1301087
[NOMBRE] => XxXxXx XXXXX
[XXXXXXXX] => P
[SEXO] => M
[XXX_NAC] => 1993-29-13
[DEPART] => XXXXXX
[DISTRITO] => 0
[ZONA] => ENCA
[LOCAL] => 8
[MESA] => 20
[ORDEN] => 42
[CEDULA] => 2692282
)

)
```

I need to use this array of arrays in my Android application, but I do not know how to retrieve the array to work with it in java
PD: the info is sended with the header Content-type: text/plain and 
i already receive the string i need to convert it to array

regards.

Comment: i have an array of array of hashmaps here?

Comment: Use php json_encode() and parse the JSON response in Java as in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888754/return-json-and-parse-in-java-android

Comment: thanks for the answer , i was getting problems of JSON_ERROR_UTF8 With json_enconde but now, i could solve it, parsing the values ​​With utf8_encode

Answer (score 0):

Use php `json_encode()` and parse the JSON response in Java as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888754/return-json-and-parse-in-java-android).

It may also be helpful to set the `content-type` header on your HTTP response from PHP:

```
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

This last is discussed in [more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script).

Cheers.